# Floating action button in Tumblr app after they apply matirial design theme

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget

I would like to ask, how you can develop an animation floating button such that one in Tumblr android app?

I know how to make floating action button, but i don't know how to animate it and make it floating on screen.

UPDATED

I found the official library

"A motion-driven animation framework for Android"

https://github.com/tumblr/Backboard

Comment: Please do some research before asking such general questions

Comment: @AndréSchild actually I did Tumblr action button is not a normal floating button!!!,I didn't find any informations, please do some search before typing general answers!!

Comment: I found the official library

"A motion-driven animation framework for Android"

https://github.com/tumblr/Backboard

Answer (score 0):

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1781 There are more such open source projects that you can use for your need. I remember seeing one such looking just like the tumblr implementation but forgot where. Do a search in github and forums like android-arsenal.com